# How to bypass Cloudfare on Steam (or similar websites) using Python requests?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, html-parsing, steam

I'm creating a python bot, which is able to collect stats from accounts about purchased games, achievements and etc.

Main problem is to parse page (https://steamcommunity.com/id/axerold2000/games/?tab=all), because steam doesn't allow to get it. As I understood from HTML page of response, it is because of Cloudfare protecting.

For example, I'll parse this user's games: https://steamcommunity.com/id/axerold2000/games?tab=all

That's how it looks like actually:[image]

And that's the response I get (whenever I use cloudscraper or not)

[image]

Here is the part of code, where I use cloudscraper to authorize (because without authorization I cannot get access to required webpages) and perform a request:

```
#authorizing via steam api
user1 = wa.WebAuth(username='USERNAME')
session = user1.cli_login('PASSWORD')

#creating cloudscraper object and performing a request
link1 = 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/axerold2000/reviews/'

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(browser={'browser':'chrome','platform':'windows','desktop': True}, sess=session)

resp = scraper.get(link1)
```

Is there any possible methods to do it only by requests? I suspect, that thing is not about cloudfare right now, because other pages (e.g. with achievements, reviews were opened without problems)